# How do you define variables in a Gradle file?

Tags: android, variables, gradle

Specifically an Android project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If  you want to define variable in project level dependancy **build.gradle(Project:NameOfYourProject)** then you can define variables in `ext`.

***like :***

```
ext {
    vCode = 340
    vName = "v3.4.0"
}
```

and if  you want to define variable in app level dependancy  **build.gradle(Module:app)** then you can use `def` for variable declaration.

**Like :**

```
def CHAT_BUCKET_NAME = '"' + CHAT_BUCKET_NAME + '"' ?: '"'
```

**Example :**

[Example](http://prntscr.com/jtw3af)

***Use it like :*** [Use variable](http://prntscr.com/jtw3sj)

Comment: links seem to be broken

Answer (score 3):

In the **top most** `build.gradle` define any variables you want inside of `ext{}`

```
ext{
    my_version = "16.0.0"
}
```

And then use it in sub folder .gradle files automatically (Android Studio) with

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:$my_version"
```

Comment: You can also declare an `ext {...}` block in a module's `build.gradle` file. The `ext{}` block goes at the top level of the file in either case.